# Center image on product page in woocommerce by custom css

Tags: php, image, center

I'm trying to center image in custom css but can't find good solution.
Can anyone take a look?

The website :

And image of this piarate should be centered. I need to do it for each single product.

I try like that :

```css
.woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 images{
    max-width: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
}


.figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper{
    max-width: 250px;
   vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

How can i center this image in every single product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and tell me if it works:

```
.woocommerce-page div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

instead of

```
.woocommerce-page div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper {
  margin: 0; }
```